# How do I install OBApps in Lubuntu 13.04?

Tags: python, lubuntu, openbox

`OBApps` is a graphical tool for configuring per-application settings in Openbox. While it's possible to make per-application settings by editing `lubuntu-rc.xml` as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Launching_Windows_Maximized), a GUI approach may be preferable.

Unfortunately, `OBApps` isn't available in Ubuntu's repos but is available as a `.tar.gz` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/obapps/files/obapps-0.1.7.tar.gz/download). Extracting this tar yields three Python scripts and a README. To quote from the README:

> To install:
>
> `sudo python setup.py install`, or just put obapps somewhere 
>   on your path and make sure it's executable
>
> Requires:
>
> wxPython (2.8.0+), python-xlib

but `apt-cache search wxpython` or `apt-cache search wxPython` doesn't list a package of that name. Does that mean I cannot install OBApps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [wiki at wxpython.org](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian) indicates that `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n`should meet the requirement for "wxPython".

With those packages installed, the rest is simple: `sudo python setup.py install`.